# requests sessions: do cookies really persist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, cookies, python-requests

I have experiment with sessions in `requests`. One thing confuses me: when I reuse a session, on the second request the cookies are empty.

This short example boils it down, and the result is same with all host I try.

```
import requests
import time

# ==== First Request ====
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url="http://www.example.com")
print(response.cookies)
# <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie UID=759854d4058cf52df60bbbe2a19d1402f5aee (...)

time.sleep(2)

# ==== Second Request ====
response = session.get(url="http://www.example.com")
print(response.cookies)
# <RequestsCookieJar[]> (EMPTY!)
```

But according to [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects):

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across
>   requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the
>   Session instance (...)

What am I missing?

**Edit:** the answer explained that I was doing wrong. And `dir(session)` made me realize that the cookies were stored in `session.cookies`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you check the response's http header instead of the request.

Your first request creates the session on the server for the first time and the server responds to your request with the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header. This is what you see in the printout of the first response.

In your second request, the session is already created, therefore the server doesn't need to include the cookie in its response.

Try to examine your requests instead of the responses.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Now I can see that the cookies are persistent in `session.cookies`